# How to add two Objects in objects items

Tags: javascript

Recently, I've asked a question about how to create a shortand for addEventListener, the result was:

```
var dom = {
  id: function(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    return Object.create(element, {
      on: {
        value(event, fn, options) {
          element.addEventListener(event, fn, options);
        }
      }
    })
  }
};
```

what if I wanted to add two Object.create? How would I return it? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you want to add a second method, add it after on(). If you run Object.create again, you'll lose the on() method.

Comment: does it mean I have to do something like dom.id.funcName = function(param) {}?

Comment: @user14945188 I don't understand how this is supposed to work. When I create a div with `id="el"` and do `dom.id("el").on("click", doThis());`, it fires `doThis()` immediately and the click event isn't attached. Can you add the code showing its implementation?

Comment: Let's suppose you want to change the div's innerText, you have to do: ```dom.id('el').on('click', function() { this.innerText = 'text' });```

Comment: @symlink not `doThis()` it will fire function. Pass `doThis` without `()`.

Comment: @user14945188 what do you mean by adding two `Object.create`s? Do you want to add two event listeners to the same object?

Comment: @symlink No, I want to add an Object.create that gets/changes the given element innerText, without changing the first event listener.

Comment: @user14945188 I'm not sure if I completely understand, but I offered a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can add several functions to dom and chain them by returning this inside each function. Then call them like this:

```
dom.id("el").on("click",()=>console.log("clicked") ).changeText("replacement text");
```

```js
var dom = {
  id: function(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    return Object.create(element, {
      on: {
        value(event, fn, options) {
          element.addEventListener(event, fn, options);
          return this;
        }
      },
      changeText: {
        value(text) {
          element.innerText = text;
          return this;
        }
      }
    })
  }
};

dom.id("el").on("click", () => console.log("clicked") ).changeText("replacement text");
```

```html
<div id="el">This text will be replaced</div>
```